# Replacing a font in many illustrator files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I have several hundred Illustrator files that are formatted similarly, and for legal reasons I need to replace a font in all of them. Even with the 'Find font' tool, that's a hell of a lot of fonts to replace by hand.

Is there some way of automating it? For example, using Bridge? Illustrator (CS5) doesn't offer many options in Bridge, compared to the automation options offered by Photoshop. I also don't see any option for running actions on multiple Illustrator files.

Also, creating a repeatable action for replacing the font doesn't seem to work: instead of repeating my action, it brings up the dialog box an waits for me to tell it to replace them.

As a programmer I'm prepared to edit the files directly if it can be done without breaking them.

---

*Update:* The 'Batch...' menu item from Illustrator's actions panel menu allows the same action to be performed on a folder of files. It doesn't fix the Find Fonts action waiting for input though. Toggling the dialog off makes the action do nothing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might take a look at scripting.

[This link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2835159) is to the Adobe forums with a discussion regarding scripts to alter fonts in Illustrator CS4. The same scripts should function in CS5 or CS6.

[**Illustrator Scripting Reference (click here)**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html)

Comment: I had no idea you could use Javascript to control Adobe apps. I knew about the AppleScript equivalent, and was starting to eye one of the Macs in the office for this purpose.

Comment: Okay, there's a good reason for that. It's *really* badly documented.

Comment: I assume you looked here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html

Comment: Yes, but that's pretty rough documentation compared to a lot of modern languages. It took a lot of trial and error, but this approach is starting to work for me - it is replacing fonts. I'll post the complete script when I've finished it.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but added an answer of my own with the detailed solution I worked out.

Answer (score 6):

Using Actions may help, and is a good strategy if you can get it to work (Actioning several Find Font commands for all the different type styles you have).

---

Another method, if you're game, is using a text editor to edit the documents. It's a bit more risky, but could certainly blast through thousands of documents in a very short space of time.

Here's some steps that might get you started.

1. Duplicate all the documents you wish to edit. I can't stress this enough... there's a very good chance you'll do some serious damage if you're not careful, so you'll want to work on copies.
2. Depending on the text editor you're using, you may need to rename all the files to be .txt rather than .ai. If you're using OS X, Apple's free Automator app can do this (it's in your Applications folder already). The Automator Action you want is `Rename Finder Items`.
3. Open up one of the documents in a good text editor that can Find and Replace across documents. You'll probably want something like BBEdit, Coda, Espresso, TextMate or a similar editor that's for programming. I generally use Code for this type of thing.
4. Find the portions of code that contain the font info. Adobe Illustrator .ai files contain some XML that's probably the bit you'd like to change, so they should be pretty easy to work with. I just saved a document with some text in it. Here's some of the XML in my document that shows the font (you may need to change several places).

```
 <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
    <stFnt:fontName>MyriadPro-Regular</stFnt:fontName>
    <stFnt:fontFamily>Myriad Pro</stFnt:fontFamily>
    <stFnt:fontFace>Regular</stFnt:fontFace>
    <stFnt:fontType>Open Type</stFnt:fontType>
    <stFnt:versionString>Version 2.006;PS 002.000;Core 1.0.38;makeotf.lib1.6.6565</stFnt:versionString>
    <stFnt:composite>False</stFnt:composite>
    <stFnt:fontFileName>MyriadPro-Regular.otf</stFnt:fontFileName>
 </rdf:li>
```

1. Rename all your files back to .ai.

You'll have to experiment a lot. You'll probably want to edit one document to see what the before and after look like, then try to automate it with one or several Find and Replace actions.

Once you have it working, you can apply that across all your files (remember, on the copies, not the original files!).

Is that going to work? Is it worth your time? Maybe yes, maybe no. It depends if this is a regular thing you need to do, how comfortable you are with the method and how many files you have.

**Please note that changing the font will likely move elements and text may be significantly reflowed.**

Comment: I'm fond of [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com) myself.

Comment: "It depends if this is a regular thing you need to do, how comfortable you are with the method and how many files you have." - I'm comfortable with a text find-replace, yes. I should only have to do this once, but it does affect a *lot* of files.

Comment: "Adobe Illustrator .ai files are XML" - Not quite, they're a Postscript derivative that has some embedded XML in the header.

Comment: @MarcusDowning Thanks for the clarification. I'll edit the reply to match your comment. You're right, AI PDF (.ai) files don't seem to be all XML. I guess you could save as EPS as well (also not XML!).

Comment: I'd love to know how you go with this, because I haven't done it myself... I just thought that it should be possible, given what you're after.

Comment: Are you certain that replacing the <rdf:li> element is sufficient? How is that resource referenced at other places in the file? Won't it just leave broken references?

Comment: I suspect I'll have to make sure the length of the embedded XML is the same as before the edit, to avoid upsetting the PS embedding...

Comment: "Please note that changing the font will likely move elements and text may be significantly reflowed." - I've chosen a replacement font with nearly-identical character sizes and a similar appearance, so this should be kept to a minimum.

Comment: Note that .ai files may contain binary data, this might get munged by a text editor. Perhaps a hex editor would be a more appropriate application to use. I am also wondering about embedded font subsets: I expect such fonts would not be editable in the manner described here.

Comment: I don't think it embeds fonts until you turn it into a PDF. But yes, I'll have to be careful not to break any binary data.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the accepted answer, here are some scripts that I've worked out to do the job.

- [Find all the fonts used](https://gist.github.com/2778294)
- [Replace the fonts](https://gist.github.com/2778305)

Use the first script to get the exact name of the fonts that are being used. Then edit the array at the top of the second script with the names of fonts you want to substitute.

```
var substitutions = [
  ['BellGothic BT', 'Bold',         'Roboto', 'Condensed'],
  ['BellGothic Blk BT', 'Black',    'Roboto', 'Bold Condensed'],
];
```

Note that on large folders these scripts might take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

in Illustrator CC you can do it simply by going to Type> find font.
choose which fonts you want to replace with what.

[image]

this worked for me.

Comment: This works for a **single document** not multiple files. You'd have to do this over and over for each file you need to address. This is why scripting is probably a better solution.