# Is there a script that can list the fonts used in hundreds of ai files?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, font-identification, illustrator-scripting

I have several hundred packaged `.ai` files but I need to know all of the fonts used is there a script or something that can generate a list of all the fonts?

Comment: The OP's answer in [Replacing a font in many illustrator files](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/replacing-a-font-in-many-illustrator-files) has the appropriate script.